# Vertica- easy on main memory?

Tags: vertica

I'm new to Vertica and have been reading lots of material and not much hands-on yet. From what I have read so far I understand that the Read-only store (ROS) which really answers the queries runs fully from the disk and does not use the main memory at all. Does that mean that there is no concept of query caching in Vertica? Is this  because of the "shared-nothing" architecture?

Considering the above- does it mean that Vertica does not really need GBs of memory for answering queries? I know that the Write-only Store (WOS) works mainly out of the memory and hence WOS would need memmory. But considering from an OLAP usage (where reads are more complex when compared to writes) it looks like Vertica is easy on memory.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

Vertica's performance is affected by memory.

When attempting to join 2 large tables (for example) it tries to do Hash/Merge/whatever join in memory. When the data won't fit it 'spills to disk' which results in a much slower process than being in memory.

Vertica will be functional, but have a negative impact on performance, if it doesn't have sufficient memory. (Sufficient left intentionally vague)

Answer (score 0):

ROS and WOS stand for read-optimized store and write-optimized store, not read-only and write-only.

On a schedule of its own choosing, Vertica will move tuples from WOS to ROS on a table by table basis. Ultimately, read/query performance depends on how data is stored on disk.

Certainly, there are memory limitations as Nija describes. But you should never regard data in WOS as permanently resident there. Expect it to eventually move into ROS in the long term.

Answer (score 0):

RE: Nija - actually, MergeJoin and other sort based optimizations use relatively little memory.

WOS is used to amortize the cost of doing many small loads by collecting tuples from multiple loads in the Write Optimized Storage and sorting/writing them in a larger batch. Typically it does not improve query performance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Stephen comment, using the WOS collecting data, will impeove the insert performance, but if you will insert more than 100MB at once, is better to bypass the WOS and insert directly to ROS, in this way Vertica is not forced to move the data using tuples, and it will avoid other sub optimal data distribution situation.